# Appending contents to already existing div at required position

Tags: javascript, dom, append

I wish to append new divs between already existing divs as shown in example.

```
<div id='container1'>Some contents</div>
<div id='container2'>Some contents</div>
<div id='container3'>Some contents</div>
<div id='container4'>Some contents</div>
<div id='container5'>Some contents</div>
```

Now suppose I wish to append something after container 4 but before container 5 using AJAX.

How, can this be done using Javascript ??

Comment: Referer

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023194/how-to-insert-html-string-in-between-two-dom-nodes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.append in Jquery inserts content, specified by the parameter, to the end of each element in the set of matched elements.

```
$("#container4").append("<div>Something</div>");
```

Or use .before. It will prepend the new div to existing div.

```
$("#container5").prepend("<div>Something</div>");
```

See this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2FqMg/).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily with jQuery:

```
$("#container4").after("text to append");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use jquery `.after()`
[Here documentation](http://api.jquery.com/after/)

Answer (score 1):

i'm showing you using Jquery, you may get an idea :

```
jQuery('<div/>', {
    id: 'container6'
}).appendTo('#container4');
```

Or

```
$("#container5").before("<div></div>");
```